# Como fazer webscrapping de um https usando o rvest?

Tags: r, ssl, certificado-digital, web-scraping, rvest

Eu gostaria de raspar uma página que está em https usando o pacote `rvest`. No entanto, trata-se de um site com problemas no certificado de segurança. Nesses casos, é preciso desligar a verificação de SSL -- mas eu não sei como fazer isso nesse pacote. No `RCurl` e no `httr` é bem simples. Dou alguns exemplos abaixo

Essa é a página que pretendo raspar:

```
sucupira = "https://sucupira.capes.gov.br/sucupira/public/consultas/coleta/producaoIntelectual/listaProducaoIntelectual.jsf"
```

Isso é o que eu estou querendo fazer:

```
library(rvest)
read_html(sucupira) #NAO FUNCIONA
 ##  Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
 ##  Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

Obviamente, apenas retirar o "s" do https não funciona:

```
sucupira2 = "http://sucupira.capes.gov.br/sucupira/public/consultas/coleta/producaoIntelectual/listaProducaoIntelectual.jsf"

read_html(sucupira2) #CONTINUA NAO FUNCIONANDO
```

No `RCurl`, uma tentativa bem sucedida seria assim:

```
library(RCurl)
getURL(sucupira) # NAO FUNCIONA

options(RCurlOptions = 
      list(capath = system.file("CurlSSL", 
                                "cacert.pem", 
                                package = "RCurl"), 
           ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))

getURL(sucupira) # AGORA FUNCIONA
```

No `httr` seria assim:

```
library(httr)
GET(sucupira) # NAO FUNCIONA

set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ))
GET(sucupira) # AGORA FUNCIONA
```

Meu propósito é aprender a usar o `rvest`. Então eu *não gostaria*, se possível, de usar estratégias do tipo:

```
read_html(GET(sucupira)) # a resposta do comando GET do httr é
                         # passada para o read_html do rvest
```

Comment: Você pode considerar que "acessar uma página" (`httr`) é uma tarefa diferente de "manipular um arquivo html" (`rvest`). Meus web scrapers geralmente contêm a sequência `httr::GET(x) %>% httr::content('text') %>% xml2::read_html() %>% rvest::html_XXX() `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso não parece ser possível usando o pacote `rvest`.

Lendo o código fonte, vemos que a função `read_html` é um wrapper da função `read_xml`. O código fonte está disponível neste [link](https://github.com/hadley/xml2/blob/master/R/xml_parse.R).

A função `read_xml` usa algum método dependendo do tipo de input, que pode ser `character`, `raw` ou `connection`.

Quando passamos uma URL, para a função `read_xml`, ela o converte para uma conexão e em seguida o lê como um `raw`.

Abaixo está o método para conexões da função `read_xml`

```
read_xml.connection <- function(x, encoding = "", n = 64 * 1024,
                                verbose = FALSE, ..., base_url = "",
                                as_html = FALSE) {
  if (!isOpen(x)) {
    open(x, "rb")
    on.exit(close(x))
  }

  raw <- read_connection_(x, n)
  read_xml.raw(raw, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html)
}
```

Veja que ele usa a função `open` do `base`.

Do help do `open` lemos:

> Note that the https:// URL scheme is not supported by the internal
>   method except on Windows. There it is only supported if --internet2 or
>   setInternet2(TRUE) was used (to make use of Windows internal
>   functions), and then only if the certificate is considered to be
>   valid. With that option only, the http://user:pass@site notation for
>   sites requiring authentication is also accepted.

Ou seja, https só é suportado em windows, se `setInternet2(TRUE)` for usado antes. Neste caso, só funcionaria se o certificado fosse válido.

Tudo isso p/ explicar que não existe uma forma nativa, ou uma simples mudança de argumento no `rvest` que permita ler páginas https.

Acredito que o melhor método seja mesmo `read_html(GET(sucupira))`que nem vc mesmo sugeriu. Ou mais bonitinho:

```
GET(sucupira) %>% read_html()
```

---

Se no método da função `read_xml.connection` você trocasse a linha `open(x, "rb")` por `url(x,"rb", method = "libcurl")` é provável que funcionasse...

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Apesar de já ter se passado muito tempo, é possível desabilitar a verificação do certificado no `httr` com efeito também no `rvest`.

Fiz assim:

```
library(httr)

set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ))

# agora acesso o site
url <- 'https://cei.b3.com.br/CEI_Responsivo/'
sessao <- html_session(url)
```

Desta forma o `rvest` não reclamou do certificado.

HTH,